# How to fix state variable contents not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on building out a small application. Currently I'm stuck at trying to display the response given from my back-end.

I've been using [this guide](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/) to implement a data fetching hook, and everything works except for trying to display the returned entries in a list.

Here is what my code in the component looks like:

```
    import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from 'axios';

    function Search() {
        const [zone, setZone] = useState('');
        const [results, setResults] = useState({entries: []});
        const [url, setUrl] = useState(
            `http://localhost:4000/entries/view/`
        );

        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchEntries = async () => {
                const result = await axios.get(url);
                setResults({entries: result.entries});
            };

            fetchEntries();
        }, [url]);

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <input type="text" value={zone} onChange={e => setZone(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="btn-primary" onClick={() => 
                    setUrl(`http://localhost:4000/entries/view/${zone}`)
                }>
                    Search
                </button>
                <ul>
                    {results.entries.map(item => (
                        <li key={item._id}>
                            <div>{item.entry_description}</div>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
    export default Search;
```

And here is a sample of what the API response looks like:

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "_id": "5d365d9af8b0625f345a8cea",
            "entry_description": "Test ui",
            "entry_time": "Now",
            "entry_author": "Me",
            "entry_zone": "12345",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d367e3bbd8b13188c0d638b",
            "entry_description": "Test still?",
            "entry_time": "Now",
            "entry_author": "Me",
            "entry_zone": "12345",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Current error message I'm receiving is:

```
The above error occurred in the <Search> component:
    in Search (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:21)
    in div (at App.js:14)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:13)
    in App (at src/index.js:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

TypeError: results.entries is undefined
home.component.js:30

TypeError: results.entries is undefined
home.component.js:30
```

I really appreciate any help figuring out what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've got it working now, although I don't quite understand it. I used [this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvvkoo8pq3) and changed some of the names to work with my variable names. I think the fix has something to do with the useEffect() dependency in this code including the query variable. In my original code, I combined them into a url, and then didn't also include the zone variable in the dependency.

Here's my final code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function Search() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ entries: [] });
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('Enter zone');

  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;

    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await axios('http://localhost:4000/entries/view/' + query);
      if (!ignore) setData(result.data);
    }

    fetchData();
    return () => { ignore = true; }
  }, [query]);

  return (
    <>
      <input value={query} onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      <ul>
        {data.entries.map(item => (
          <li key={item._id}>
            <p>{item.entry_description}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be wrapping the api result in an array, whereas you just need to assign it to enteries

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEntries = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(url);
            setResults({entries: result.entries});
        };

        fetchEntries();
    }, [url]);
```

Comment: I made that change and I'm still getting the "results.entries is undefined". I edited my post to reflect that change.